# dynamic checkbox validation with formvalidation.io

Tags: jquery, formvalidation.io

I am creating dynamic checkboxes in jquery with all of the checkboxes being required. I cannot get the formvalidation.io to work.

Here is the html where the checkboxes are placed:

```
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group" id="divRequiredFeeList">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And here is the jquery to generate the checkboxes:

```
   $("<div />", { class: 'col-xl-12' })
                .append($("<div />", { "class": "custom-control custom-control-info custom-checkbox", "style": "display:inline" }))
                .append($("<input />", { "type": "checkbox", "id": "cb" + idkey, "class": "custom-control-input", "name": "chkRequiredFees[]", "data-fv-field": "chkRequiredFees[]" }))
                .append($("<label />", { "for": "cb" + idkey, "class": "custom-control-label required", "text": name }))
                .appendTo($('#divRequiredFeeList'));
```

This is working as intended. Here is my validation:

```
                'chkRequiredFees[]': {
                    validators: {
                        choice: {
                            message: 'Choose all required fees for acknowledgement.'
                        }
                    }
                },
```

And in addition, I have this after the dynamic checkboxes are built to ensure all are selected, where 'otherFees.length' is the number of dynamic checkboxes generated.

```
$('#frmFacilityReserve')
                    .formValidation('updateOption', 'chkRequiredFees[]', 'choice', 'min', otherFees.length);
```

If I test by placing the checkboxes in the html directly, it works. I have checked the generated html against just hard-coding the checkboxes, and it seems to be the same. I don't know why it is not working when dynamically building the checkboxes. I have worked on this for 2 days, trying everything I can find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i figured it out.

Comment: I needed to add the 'form-group' class in my dynamic code and then use 'addfield' to add the field to the validation.


            var uniqueKey = '#txt' + idkey;
            $option = $('#frmFacilityReserve').find(uniqueKey);
            
            $('#frmFacilityReserve').formValidation('addField', $option);